# Proving $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n(1+a_{k})\leq e$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

If $a_{k}>-1$, $\forall 1\leq k\leq n$ such that :
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_{k}}{1+a_{k}x}\leq1\;\; ,\forall x\in[0,1]
$$
Then how can we show that :
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_{k})\leq e
$$

Comment: What have you tried? Show your efforts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that :
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_{k}}{1+a_{k}x}\;\text{d}x=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(1+a_{k})=\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_{k})\right)\leq1
$$
Therefore :
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_{k})\leq e
$$

Answer (score 3):

Integrating the identity
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{1+a_kx}\leqslant 1 $$
between $0$ and $1$ gives
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\log(1+a_k)\leqslant 1$$
Thus
$$ \prod_{k=1}^n(1+a_k)=\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\log(1+a_k)\right)\leqslant e$$